# Java - Compare 2 int Arrays and judge them based on their values

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have a set of 2 int Arrays containing the same amount of numbers

for example

```
int[] array1 = {1,3,5,5,2}
int[] array2 = {5,3,4,4,4}
```

I need to compare them based on 2 criteria

1. How many elements have the same value on the same index
2. How many elements have the same value on a different index

And return an array of integers presenting the values

I have a few examples so you can understand better:

```
   int[] array0 = {1,3,5,5,2};
   int[] array1 = {5,3,4,4,4};
   int[] array2 = {5,3,4,4,5};
   int[] array3 = {2,3,2,2,4};
   int[] array4 = {5,5,2,1,3};
   int[] array5 = {3,1,5,5,2};
   int[] array6 = {1,3,5,5,2};

   compare(array0,array1); //this would return 1,1
   compare(array0,array2); //this would return 1,2
   compare(array0,array3); //this would return 1,1
   compare(array0,array4); //this would return 0,5
   compare(array0,array5); //this would return 3,2
   compare(array0,array6); //this would return 5,0
```

For the first number it's easy, I just need to check if element on index i of array1 is the same as in array2.

I have problems producing the second number because the lowest number from one of the arrays should be taken.
If I just look if element of array1 is somewhere in array2 it produces a wrong result in some cases.

if you look at

```
int[] array1 = {1,3,5,5,2}
```

and

```
int[] array3 = {2,3,2,2,4};
```

and check if array1 has the same contents as array3 on an index, it would return 3 numbers are equal but on a different spot which is wrong because it should judge from the lowest number and the result there should be 1.

If I switch it around to compare if array3 has the same contents as array1 on some index it works for this case but not for others.

Any ideas on how to approach this, I'm pretty clueless?

Comment: Why don't you use more powerful mechanisms available in Java than arrays - *The collection framework*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public void compare(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int sameIndex = 0;
    int diffIndex = 0;
    //Made two new empty arrays to save the status of each element in the corresponding array, whether it has been checked our not, if not, it'd be null.
    String[] arrayAstatus = new String[arrayA.length];
    String[] arrayBstatus = new String[arrayB.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {            
        if (arrayA[i] == arrayB[i] || arrayAstatus[i] != null) {
            sameIndex++;
            continue;
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayB.length; a++) {
            if (a == i || arrayBstatus[a] != null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (arrayA[i] == arrayB[a]) {
                arrayAstatus[i] = "checked";
                arrayBstatus[a] = "checked";
                diffIndex++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sameIndex + ", " + diffIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Clone the two input integer arrays.
- Check and see if the elements have the same value on the same index.
- If so, add 1 to the same index counter and change the values in the input integer arrays to -1 (or a number less than the smallest valid value).
- Check and see if the elements have the same value using a nested for loop.  In other words, check the first element of the first integer array with all the elements of the second integer array.  Skip the element that has the same index in both arrays, and skip elements that are less than the smallest valid value.
- If so, add 1 to the different index counter and change the values in the input integer arrays to -1 (or a number less than the smallest valid value).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for the second condition, you could try removing the numbers from the arrays and breaking out of the loop once they are found to have a match.  You could have temporary arrays that you set to the values of the original arrays.  Then check the value of `array1[0]` against all the values in `array3`.  When a match is found, remove the number from both arrays and check `array1[1]` against all the values in `array3`.

So when you check `array1[4]` against `array3[0]`, you will get a match.  Then you will remove both numbers and break out of the loop.  There are no more numbers to check in `array1`, so the result would be 1.

I think this would clear up the issue of counting the same value twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Set with numbers already visited. You would something like: (not testing if this code runs, it's just to give you an idea)

```
public int[] compare(int[] first, int[] second) {
     Set<Integer> numbersFoundInFirstArray = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
     Set<Integer> numbersFoundInSecondArray = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
     int inSameIndex = 0;
     int inDifferentIndex = 0;

     for (int i; i < first.length; i++) {
         if (first[i] == second[i]) {
             inSameIndex++;
         }
         if (numbersFoundInFirstArray.contains(second[i])) {
             inDifferentIndex++;
         }
         if (numbersFoundInSecondArray.contains(first[i])) {
             inDifferentIndex++;
         }
         numbersFoundInFirstArray.add(first[i]);
         numbersFoundInSecondArray.add(second[i]);
     }
     return new int[] {inSameIndex, inDifferentIndex};
}
```

The contains comparison in set has O(1) if I remenber well. The property of Set is that you will only have one element of a certain type. So, if you add 1 two times, it will have only one reference of 1. This way, you will only test if the current number was already found in the other array :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose all the arrays into a tree-like structure which will basically index all the unique values in all arrays and store pointers to their positions in the array and which array.  The basic blueprint structure for that tree would be:

```
uniqElemVal->arrayIndx->arrayID = true
```

Where uniqElemVal would be 1,3,5,2 for 1,3,5,5,2, 2,3,4 for 2,3,2,2,4, etc, all unionized

arrayIndx would be for 1 in the 1st array 0, for 5 would be 2 and 3 etc.

array ID is something arbitrary that lets you key each array, e.g. 1 for the first, 2 for the second etc.

So in this case:

```
#1st array
1->0->1
3->1->1
5->2->1
5->3->1
2->4->1

#2nd array
2->0->2    
3->1->2 
3->2->2
2->3->2
2->4->2
4->5->2
```

Then when you traverse this tree, whenever you have a 2nd level node with more than 1 leafs, that means that there is a match for that particular element value in the particular position across multiple arrays.

I would personally define this tree as

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>
```

So whenever you have a leaf array list with >1 elements, that means you have a match

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this sounds like a really bad idea. Don't return an array where each index means something different and cryptic. Make two methods: compareSameIndex(array, array) and compareDifferentIndex(array, array).

To the actual implementation of how these, you could check every index in the first array to see if they appear anywhere in the second array and call that just compare(). Then compareDifferentIndex() becomes compare()-compareSameIndex().  For instance:

```
public int compare (int[] array0, int[] array1) {
  int matches = 0;
  List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);

  for (int curInt : array0) {
    if (list1.contains(curInt)) {
      matches++;
    }
  }
  return matches;
}

public int compareSameIndex(int[] array0, int[] array1) {
  int matches = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < array0.length; i++) {
    if (array0[i] == array1[i]) {
      matches++
    }
  }
  return matches;
}

public int compareDifferentIndex(int[] array0, int[] array1) {
  return compare(array0, array1) - compareSameIndex(array0, array1);
}
```

The requirements seem a little vague about what happens when the same number appears twice but you could build that logic into compare() to accommodate. Also you could optimize this for very large arrays where you don't check the same number twice, but this would be the general approach I would take.

Answer (score 0):

Checking arguments is just good practice.
There are probably some minor optimizations that can be done here, but a Hash will let you store positions you've already visited so as to not count them more then once.

```
 private int[] compare(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    int same_index = 0;
    Hashtable differences = new Hashtable();
    int diff_count = 0;
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array Size is not identical.");
    } else {
       for(int count = 0; count < arr1.length; count++){
          if (arr1[count] == arr2[count]{
              same_index++;
              differences.put(count, null);
          } else {
              for (int count2 = 0; count2 < arr1.length; count2++){
                  if(!differences.containsKey(count2) && arr1[count] == arr2[count2]){
                      differences.put(count2, null);
                      diff_count++;
                  }

              }                  
          }
       }
    }
    int[] returnArray = new int[2];
    returnArray[0] = same_count;
    returnArray[1] = diff_count;
    return (returnArray);
 }
```